# Holdable html button on mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, html, ios, user-interface, button

I have a simple web button

```
<button id="awesome" style="height:150px; width:500px"></button>
```

And using safari on the desktop, I can do real time things in response to when the button is held down using . . .

```
document.getElementById('awesome').onmousedown = function() {
    responding = true;
//  console.log("on");
};

document.getElementById('awesome').onmouseup = function() {
    responding = false;
//  console.log("off");
};
```

But when I run this on Safari on the iPhone, holding the button makes the copy paste menu appear, and I do not get the behaviour I desire. What do I modify to get the same intended response across platforms?

Comment: You need to use touch events for that. 

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Comment: You can use `taphold` from [jQueryMobile](https://api.jquerymobile.com/taphold/)

Comment: Ha - voting to close my own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because mobile phones don't have a mouse. The mobile browser will emulate some events just to provide a good experience for websites that haven't been optimised for mobile usage (such as the click event) but the two events you mentioned aren't emulated.

You will need to use touch events for mobile: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

There's a few ways you can approach this:

1. Look for library that does the event binding for you, there's probably a couple out there
2. Detect the environment and bind one set of events or the other.
3. Bind to both touch and mouse events. If a mouse event you want to use is being emulated you can either rely on the emulation for that one event, or `preventDefault()` and maybe `stopPropagation` in the appropriate touch event to stop the mouse event being triggered on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try the `ontouchstart` and `ontouchend` events? 
[ontouchstart MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchstart)
[ontouchend MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchend)